# How does Google play's search work?

Tags: android, search, google-play

I have recently released an app on Google play [see here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.liam.alford.babehunter.ad)
When using Google play's search, the only way it comes up is if search the exact name. Does anyone know how to improve this.

I know there is a lot of competition for an app of this nature, however searching using a the term 'hot babes' returned over 1000 results and in the top 20 was game called 'fishing women'.

The description did contain the word hot, but no mention of babes as far as i could see.

Does any one know the best way to get an app higher up the search pile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no references only experience. It's a style of SEO so there is no actual documentation.

From my experience it goes on:

- Title
- Relevant keywords in your description
- Amount of downloads
- Speed of downloads vs release date
- Star rating

Comment: Inserting more key words into the title worked a treat.

Comment: It should be noted that it takes some time before relevant keywords from the title is indexed by google crawlers while the title is indexed right away.